# What does this line mean?

Tags: grammaire

> Le plaisir de l'amour est *d'aimer*, et l'on est plus heureux  par la passion que *l'on a que par celle* que l'on donne.

What does it mean? I'm a bit lost in

1. What does *d'aimer* mean, "the love ", "be loved " or "to love"?
2. What does *l'on a que par celle* mean, especially, what does *celle* refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The love" : l'amour ; "be loved" : être aimé, "to love" : aimer.

But "est d'aimer" is "**est de**" + "**aimer**". If you have a voyel word after "**de**" it become "**d'**" for ease of pronunciation. Like in "mourir d'amour" or "amourette d'été". Another use of "**est de**" would be "L'objectif principal est de contribuer..." (*The overarching aim **is to** contribute...*)

Finally, "Celle" refer to "la passion" :

> The pleasure in love is to love, and one is happier by the passion one has than by **the one** one gives.

Comment: Do you mean the translation shall be "one is happier by the passion (given by others, or, be loved) than by the one that one gives (to love)."?

Comment: Yeahs sorry it was'nt clear with "one's passion" I edited the translation so it's clearer ("the passion one has")